# Is there a validate the cardinality of SQL joins?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When using SQL (snowflake) I often join tables.

I can never be 100% sure that the join is a one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many, etc...

In Python pandas this is a setting in merge statements that will assert that the join is of the expected kind.

Is there an equivalent in SQL?

#### EDIT: This is the pandas API (which I like)

```py
table1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'userId': [1,2,3], 
    'age':[20,30,40]
})


#|   userId |   age |
#|---------:|------:|
#|        1 |    20 |
#|        2 |    30 |
#|        3 |    40 |

table2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'userId': [1,2,2,3], 
    'gender':['M','M','F', 'F'], 
    'gender_valid_to_date': [None, '2020-01-01', None, None]
})

#|   userId | gender   | gender_valid_to_date   |
#|---------:|:---------|:-----------------------|
#|        1 | M        |                        |
#|        2 | M        | 2020-01-01             |
#|        2 | F        |                        |
#|        3 | F        |                        |

pd.merge(table1, table2, on='userId', how='left', validate='one_to_one')

# This raises a merge error
```

> MergeError: Merge keys are not unique in right dataset; not a one-to-one merge

You can imagine it's easy to naively go for a LEFT JOIN here assuming it'd just add the gender column, but you know what they say about assuming...

In this case the "right" solution to get a table and the user's current gender is

```sql
SELECT 
   userId, 
   age, 
   gender AS current_gender 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userId, gender FROM table2 WHERE gender_valid_to_date is Null
) t2 ON t2.userId = t1.userId
```

However, you can see how this can get complicated to "check" constantly.

Comment: @MYK If the real use case is the ability to preserve the history(column gender_valid_to_date indicates that) but during query choose only the current one then simply create a view like `table2_current` which will return only newest row(single per userId). You could even go one step further and use [append-only approach](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/data-vault-technique-immutable-storage/)

Comment: The issue is to have a safeguard against developers writing bad queries when working under pressure. Ideally this "validate" cardinality thing (if it existed) would help avoid errors as shown in the example. It happens when developers have a different mental model than the data, and then you have to start debugging or going to the documentation.

Comment: Pandas in python has it for this reason, just to make sure the join is behaving as one would expect

Comment: I'm not an expert on pandas but from the example provided in the question the check appears to be in relation to merges rather than generic joins. If we are just talking about merges then Snowflake has similar controls (look at the ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE parameter). If you are talking about checking generic joins then I'm not aware of anything that does this in standard SQL (though you might be able to "roll your own"). To help your developers, you should have a properly documented data model and your developers should know how to construct, and test/debug, their queries step-by-step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate answer to this question is that Snowflake itself does not provide this feature built-in, although IMO it would be an interesting and useful new feature (I might even call it an "innovation") in data warehouses.

In order to make this job easier, save all non-trivial query results to a view or temporary table.

---

The first solution is to craft ad-hoc validity checks to be run on the resulting view or table.

You can do this in SQL directly by putting each check into a field or row of a table and visually ensuring that they are all `TRUE`.

In the example you gave, if can save the results to `joined_1_2`, then you can run a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      user_id, count(*) as n
    FROM joined_1_2
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING n > 1
  ) AS no_duplicates
;
```

Depending on how fancy and/or automated you want things to be, can write stored procedures, Python scripts, etc. to run such queries and provide various outputs based on their results. The Python option could be particularly interesting, as you can use native Python `assert` statements or even a test framework like Pytest.

If these joins are being automated in some kind of recurring ETL/ELT pipeline, you might also want to consider using a tool like [Great Expectations](https://greatexpectations.io/gx-oss) to implement data quality and correctness checks.

---

Another strategy is to impose constraints on the temporary tables that you create.

For example, you can impose a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on the table that is intended to hold the results of a 1:1 join. Then if the data being inserted into that table results in duplicated primary keys, then you know that there is a problem in the source tables.

I think this technique is the most direct analogy of setting `validate=` in Pandas, but it requires a bit more setup and forethought. Unfortunately, I don't think Snowflake supports combining constraints (e.g. foreign key) with [create-table-as-select](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#variant-syntax) syntax, so you might need to run a separate `CREATE TABLE` command for every query output, which can be very annoying if you have a lot of columns and you only want to check a few of them.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I am using DBT to create a lot of tables, so I can add these "checks" as scheduled tests - not ideal but as you say... "not implemented"

Comment: I can imagine the syntax for this "new" join check, something like `table1 LEFT [INJECTIVE|BIJECTIVE|SURJECTIVE] [LEFT|RIGHT|INNER|OUTER] JOIN table2`

Comment: I like that idea. I think it might be better as a suffix, e.g. `LEFT JOIN table 2 [ INJECTIVE | SURJECTIVE | BIJECTIVE ] [ ON ... | USING (...) ]`

Comment: @MYK you might also want to consider [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75404917/2954547) which demonstrates using the `MERGE` command, instead of just creating tables with ad-hoc checks.

Comment: The merge command is interesting, though hard to get my head around it ;D

Answer (score 2):

Give a try with   **ERROR_ON_NONDETERMINISTIC_MERGE** which helps to raise an error in case if there are dup's which comes from join and try to merge. May be this could help you.

```
CREATE TABLE T1(USERID NUMBER, NAME STRING); 
CREATE TABLE T2(USERID NUMBER, NAME STRING); 
INSERT INTO
    T1 VALUES(1, 'E'),(1, 'D'),(2, 'C'); 
 INSERT INTO
    T2 VALUES(1, 'A'),(1, 'B'),(2, 'C'); 
MERGE INTO T2 USING (
        Select
            T1.USERID,
            T1.NAME
        FROM
            T1
    ) AS T1 ON T1.USERID = T2.USERID(+)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
    T2.USERID = T1.USERID,
    T2.NAME = T1.NAME;
```

Answer (score -1):

No, there isn’t (not that I’m aware of). A SQL join is normally 1 to many, is less commonly 1 to 1 and there is no such thing as a many to many join (hence the need for intersection tables to model many to many relationships).

Is there a specific reason why you need to know the join type or why you don’t know it anyway - I’m not sure how you would write almost any SQL query if you didn’t already know the data model?

Comment: It happens when you have messy real world data. Say, if you need to join a userId|email table with a userId|username table on userId, but userId has duplicates in the username table due to a username change, etc... It happens often in data science.

Comment: There is almost always a way to get LEFT JOINs to work as a way to enrich the entities in the left table with data from the right table, but one has to be careful to avoid introducing duplicates.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer. The fact that SQL joins are "usually" in one of a few specific categories is irrelevant to the problem under discussion: that the data might not meet the criteria for the type of join that you intend to perform, and you want to assert that the criteria are in fact met.